# .NET 6 IDispatch client implementation crash

Tags: c#, .net-core, com-interop, .net-6.0, idispatch

.NET 6 has trouble calling its own `IDispatch` objects, if marshaled.

To reproduce:

```
if (Array.IndexOf(Environment.GetCommandLineArgs(), "/s")>=0) //Server
{
    Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
    {
        Hello h = new Hello();
        new RunningObjectTable().Register("HelloTest", h);
        Thread.Sleep(1000 * 3600);

    }));
    t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.MTA);
    t.Start();
    Thread.Sleep(1000 * 3600);
}
else //Client
{
    object o = new RunningObjectTable().Get("HelloTest");
    IHello h = o as IHello;
    int f = h.Foo();
    Console.WriteLine(h);
}

[ComImport]
[Guid("00020400-0000-0000-C000-000000000046")] //IID_IDispatch
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)]
[TypeLibType(TypeLibTypeFlags.FDispatchable)]
public interface IHello
{
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.PreserveSig | MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
    [DispId(1)]
    public int Foo();
}

public class Hello: IHello
{
    public int Foo()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Hello from server");
        return 19;
    }
}
```

Run the program with /s, that's the object server. Then run another copy to become the client.

The method invocation line in the client crashes with "Member not found" - HRESULT 0x80020003, DISP_E_MEMBERNOTFOUND. Normally it would mean a bogus DISPID, but where would the discrepancy possibly come from?

One minor infraction in that code is that the interface is decorated with the IID of IDispatch. With a custom IID, as COM prescribes, it doesn't even unmarshal as the dispinterface (the `as IHello` line returns null); internally, there's a `QueryInterface` call across processes with said custom IID, the dispinterface is not registered under HKCR\Interfaces, so the interprocess COM machinery doesn't know how to marshal it. At least that's my theory.

A similar piece of logic works fine if the server is a native (C++) one. If the same C# piece is recompiled against .NET framework 4.72, it doesn't even get that far, the `o as IHello;` line returns null.

---

`RunningObjectTable` is a helper class around the ROT. For completeness' sake, here:

```
internal class RunningObjectTable
{
    #region API
    [DllImport("ole32.dll")]
    private static extern int CreateItemMoniker([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string
               lpszDelim, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string lpszItem,
               out IMoniker ppmk);

    [DllImport("ole32.dll")]
    private static extern int GetRunningObjectTable(int reserved, out IRunningObjectTable prot);
    #endregion

    private IRunningObjectTable m_rot;

    public RunningObjectTable()
    {
        GetRunningObjectTable(0, out m_rot);
    }

    private IMoniker CreateItemMoniker(string s)
    {
        IMoniker mon;
        CreateItemMoniker("", s, out mon);
        return mon;
    }

    public int Register(string ItemName, object o)
    {
        return m_rot.Register(0, o, CreateItemMoniker(ItemName));
    }

    public void Unregister(int ROTCookie)
    {
        m_rot.Revoke(ROTCookie);
    }

    public object Get(string ItemName)
    {
        object o;
        m_rot.GetObject(CreateItemMoniker(ItemName), out o);
        return o;
    }
}
```

Can someone with access to .NET Core internals please tell me what's going on?

Comment: I have the exact same behavior between .NET 6 and .NET Framework, which is DISP_E_MEMBERNOTFOUND. I don't see how that could work if you don't register a typelib. If you replace your calling code by this: `dynamic o = new RunningObjectTable().Get("HelloTest");Console.WriteLine(o.Foo);` then it works in both .NET 6 and .NET Framework.

Comment: Turns out it could :)

Comment: Your answer has nothing to do with your question

Comment: My problem was the exception with DISP_E_MEMBERNOTFOUND during a cross-process method call. It's solved. In addition, I've figured out where does the wrong DISPID come from.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's what is going on. The .NET object supports two dispinterfaces - one corresponding to `IHello`, another corresponding to `Hello` itself, and the latter is treated as the default one. I've confirmed that by adding an extra method `Bar()` to `Hello`, and checking the type in a native C++ client:

```
IUnknownPtr pUnk;
ROTGet(L"HelloTest", &pUnk);
IDispatchPtr pDisp(pUnk);
LPOLESTR Name = (LPOLESTR)L"Bar";
DISPID dispid;
hr = pDisp->GetIDsOfNames(IID_NULL, &Name, 1, 0, &dispid);
```

And I got S_OK and a valid, if bogus, DISPID. I then requested a DISPID for `Foo` in the same way, and got another bogus DISPID.

I've found two ways to fix that.

---

One, tell the framework that it should not implicitly generate a dispinterface for `Hello`. Annotate the class with `[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]`, and it won't. The explicit check for the DISPID of `Foo` confirms that. The unmarshaled dispinterface in the client corresponds to `IHello`, and the methods work as expected.

---

Another approach, give `IHello` an identity (an IID) and make it marshalable. If I slap a custom GUID on that interface, and add a key with that GUID to HKCR\Interfaces, providing `ProxyStubClsid32` equals to `{00020420-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}` (that's PSDispatch, the proxy/stub CLSID for `IDispatch`), the fragment also works.

One other way to tell COM that an IID corresponds to a dispinterface and should be marshaled as one is via implementing `IStdMarshalInfo`. I didn't try this.

---

One more note: *the Hello class has to be declared public* for this to work. If it's not, for some reason the `as IHello` returns null.